# Can I prepend table to another table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prepend table "new" to table "lasttable" using jQuery but I cannot get the result. Am I doing the right thing or I misunderstood the meaning of prepend?

```
<table id ="lasttable" class="add" border="1px" width="100%">
<tr class="header"><td class="location" colspan="7">New Item</td></tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#lasttable").prepend("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">"
+"<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>
+"</tbody></table>");
```

Comment: Your table has an id of `lasttable` but in your js you are referencing `#lasttablet`...

Comment: You have `#lasttablet` in the selector, not `#lasttable`

Comment: Sorry for my typo mistake, it is #lasttable somehow when I type in here it was wrong... still not working.

Comment: Is your jQuery written inside $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
$("#lasttablet") //this is wrong selector since your id is lasttable
```

change to

```
$("#lasttable")
```

**UPDATED**

replace this

```
$("#lasttable").prepend("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">"
+"<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>
+"</tbody></table>");
```

with

```
$("#lasttable").prepend("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\"><tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dhqqv/) here

problem was with escaping `"`, REmove the`+` sign and use it as a single string.. that should work..

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the "#lasttablet" to "#lasttable" still not showing.

Comment: I tested in fiddle it seems to work but not in my code so I guess it is good just need to look at my code again. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I did but on my code it didn't show the result, I am investigating my code. Probably something else somewhere, your code is good.

Comment: just a note.. make sure you have this line of code inside `$(function(){ //here });`

Comment: I have many jquery statement and this code was at the bottom and didn't work but when I move it to the top it works. Is there requirement in jquery what should come first?

Comment: no.. but if incase your above jquery codes has a problem it won't be able to execute the other jquery codes after that....so that is what is happening here.. make sure there is no error in your jquery codes above this....

Comment: That is strange because all jq code above is working fine... I will look hard again. Thanks ago. I tried .before() didn't work but .prepend() works.

Comment: ok thanks... :).. happy coding.. let me know if any problem exists.. or post alll your jquery code..(if it is not long :) )..you can create a new  question..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your broken selector is a typo, I think you want to put the new table [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) the existing one.

```
$("#lasttable").before("new content here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code, closing quote missing from **second line**.

```
+"<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>"
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uWRAG/)**

```
$("#lasttable").prepend("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">"+"<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\">123<a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

Comment: What do you mean "no go also"? did you check the domo link in my answer?

Comment: Sir, yes fiddle is working but not with my application so I guess it is good and something I need to investigate on my side.

Comment: Did you copy pasted the code from fiddle in your application?

Comment: I have many jquery statement and this code was at the bottom and didn't work but when I move it to the top it works. Is there requirement in jquery what should come first?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of prepend is wrong here

```
The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use .append()).
```

from [Jquery Prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Ideally you should do something like

```
$("#lasttable").prepend("<tr><td><table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">"
+"<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>
+"</tbody></table></td></tr>");
```

Prepend() will add tr element inside your table:lasttable at the starting position
OR
If you want to add a table before your existing table then you can use before() instead of prepend()
Something like:

```
$("#lasttable").before("<tr><td><table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\">"
+"<tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>
+"</tbody></table></td></tr>");
```

Comment: but if I do not want to add <tr><td>? I cannot do it? or what is the correct method to use?

Comment: so you want to add table before existing table:lasttable, Use "before" in this case

Answer (score 0):

You got one typo indeed, but either use `.before()` as karim79 suggested, *or prepend only the `<tr>`s to `#lasttable`.* I think `.before()` is easier to implement, but depending on what you're working on it might be better to prepend the TRs. Something like this:

```
var trs = $("#new").html();
$("#lasttable").prepend(tds);
```

should work.

If you do what you're doing now it will prepend the entire table to #new, and I doubt if a table inside another table is valid markup.

Comment: So I should do this?

var trs = $("#new").html("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\"><tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\"><img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\">Newly Inserted</td></tr></tbody></table>");

Answer (score 0):

try with this one: just removed the `+` and make a full string

```
 $("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\"><tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\">asdfasdfa<img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr></tbody></table>").prependTo('#lasttable');
```

and with `.prepend()`

```
 $('#lasttable').prepend("<table id=\"new\" class=\"add\" border=\"1px\" width=\"100%\"><tr class=\"header\"><td class=\"stretch\"><a class=\"eloc\" rel=\"leanModal\" href=\"#modal_location\">asdfasdfa<img src=\"images/edit-icon.png\" alt=\"Location\"></a></td><td class=\"location\" colspan=\"6\"></td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

you can checkout here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tQd/

Comment: you can achieve this with `.prependTo()` too.